# How to optimize for loop in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to roll the character string in python
Example :
s='abz'
roll=[3,2,1]

1. roll[0]=abz become bca
2. roll[1]= bca becomes cda
3. roll[2]= cda becomes dda
   I want to return dda

```
for i in roll:           
     s = ''.join([letters[(letters.index(c)+1)%len(letters)] for c in s[:i]]) + s[i:]
    
 return s
```

few test cases are failing on hackerrank due to time constraints, could someone please help me in optimizing this code.

Comment: looping and processing all data is akin to a bruteforce attack - try to look for a mathematical solution (do you _need_ to process every single string?)

Comment: I am trying to roll the string : Example : s='abz' roll=[3,2,1], roll[0]=abz become bca, roll[1]= bca becomes cda, roll[2]= cda becomes dda, I want to return dda

Comment: You could try `letters = dict(enumerate(letters))` and changing `letters.index(c)+1` to `letters[c] + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `ord()`, which is the inverse of `chr()`; once your char is a number, it's easier to +1 (don't forget to wrap)

then use a method to process each string (call this fn in a loop - once per word):

```
def increment(in_str):
  # loop over each letter
  for idx in range(0,len(in_str)):
    # convert to a number
    char_val = ord(in_str[idx])
    if char_val == ord("z"):
      # if 'z' - replace with 'a'
      in_str[idx] = chr("a")
    else:
      # otherwise +1 and convert back to char
      in_str[idx] = chr(char_val + 1)
```